# Fix three div's at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

My footer is in fixed position and I am seeing the same view on every device. I also want to fix the LinkedIn logo in white div and orange div above it. So that my website will have same view on every device. but I am not to fix them. Can anyone please help?. I have been trying from last 2 weeks.
I am not able to add my codes here. so attaching the same in screenshot
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdKY4.jpg)
[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK66G.jpg)

[This how my website currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNVDN.jpg)//i.stack.imgur.com/VNVDN.jpg

[This is how I want my website to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbvN6.jpg)//i.stack.imgur.com/VNVDN.jpg

Comment: Please [don't put the images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead, use the snippet (`[< >]`) button, and paste the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I made an easy template of what you need. It is pretty simple so I am sure that you will get the point. Please ask me whatever you want.

HTML

```
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="orange-container">

        </div>
        <div class="social-container">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="black-container">
            <p>text text text</p>
            <p>text text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .footer-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .orange-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: orange;
    }
    .social-container {
        width:100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .social-container img {
        background: red;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .black-container {
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .black-container p {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

It is better way to use display:flex or display:grid when you want to center something. Padding is used to make small spaces. Also with the display flex or grid you can easily handle the responsive view of your website pretty easy.

Please I am also advising you to check how to make your questions good [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I hope my answer will be helpful for you, and again if not, don't hesitate to ask anything :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. I will check and get back to you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. And assign to the main part flex-grow.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.w {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;  
}
.header {
  background: orange;  
  padding: 5px;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;  
}

.footer {
  background: black;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will check and get back to you..

Comment: @ekurmet13 You welcome! If you found my answer helpful it was be nice if you accept my answer.